# Not continuing the execution flow,after Jboss windows service started from batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, jboss

We are trying to start the Jboss windows service from batch file ,but Not continuing  the execution flow ,after  Jboss windows service started  from batch file . I'm using  **service install**  to start windows service.Still path in is in Jboss server path though its printing proper path with echo. Giving below errror ,

**Error On console:**

```
   E:\Downloads\Store Operations V5.5-01 Patch 4\Store Operations V5.5-01 Patch                      4\Store Operations V5.5-01 Patch 4\lib\readme.jar
  1 File(s) copied
  JAR FILES COPIED SUCCESSFULLY
  ENTER ERROR LEVEL 0
  C:\\Suite\\Store Operations V5.5 
  E:\Downloads\Store Operations V5.5-01 Patch 4\Store Operations V5.5-01 Patch       4\Store Operations V5.5-01 Patch 4
  Service JBoss Application Server 6.1 installed
  The system cannot find the drive specified.
  "C:\\Suite\\Store Operations V5.5\Backup\Patch 3.0\config\properties"
  C:\Suite\Store Operations V5.5\jboss\bin
  The system cannot find the drive specified.
 C:\Suite\Store Operations V5.5\jboss\bin
```

**Batch file code snippet:**

```
FOR %%n in (*.jar) DO (
    echo f | xcopy "%InstallerLocation%\lib\%%n" "%HOME_PATH%\lib\%%n" /Y 
    ::echo !ERRORLEVEL!
    if !ERRORLEVEL! EQU 0 (
        echo JAR FILES COPIED SUCCESSFULLY
    )       
 )
if !ERRORLEVEL! EQU 0 (
    ECHO ENTER ERROR LEVEL 0
    echo %HOME_PATH% 
    echo %InstallerLocation%

    cd  /d "C:\Suite\Store Operations V5.5\jboss\bin" 
    service install
   echo "%HOME_PATH%\Backup\Patch %folderPatchNo%.0\config\properties"
   cd

    echo JAR BACKUP SUCCESSFUL
)
if !ERRORLEVEL! EQU 4 (
        echo FAILED TO COPY THE JAR. EXITING INSTALLATION
        set Result=FAILED TO COPY THE JAR. EXITING INSTALLATION
        set STATUS=12
        cd..
        GOTO ROLLBACK
    )
cd..

:: Step 7 : Copy the properties file

::Backup of existing property file in the installation folder location
if NOT EXIST "%HOME_PATH%\Backup" (
    echo Folder does not exist. Creating Backup Folder
    md "%HOME_PATH%\Backup\Patch %folderPatchNo%.0\config\properties"
)
cd config\properties
FOR %%n in (*.*) DO echo f | xcopy "%HOME_PATH%\config\properties\%%n" "%HOME_PATH%\Backup\Patch %folderPatchNo%.0\config\properties\%%n" /Y
if !ERRORLEVEL! EQU 0 (
    echo PROPERTIES FILE BACKUP SUCCESSFUL
)
if !ERRORLEVEL! EQU 4 (
    echo FAILED TO TAKE BACKUP. EXITING INSTALLATION
    set Result=FAILED TO TAKE BACKUP. EXITING INSTALLATION
    set STATUS=15
    echo End Time : %DATE%  %TIME%
    cd..
    cd..

    GOTO END
)
```

Comment: "C:\\Suite\\ Store Operations V5.5\Backup\Patch 3.0\config\properties"this is actaul path ,but still cotroller in   C:\Suite\ Store Operations V5.5\jboss\bin JBOSS path

Comment: `C:\Suite\ Store Operations V5.5\jboss\bin` - where the space before `Store` comes from?

Comment: sorry it was my mistake here ,in actual code there is no space problem.I just removed some names which I dont want to public .that causes the space.

Comment: but the space is still there on the error excerpt....

Comment: I have edited here :-) no problem with space